# hazelcast vs hazelcast-client configuration

Tags: java, hazelcast

Have been using Hazelcast 3.4.3 with the following, basic `hazelcast.xml` for testing:

```
<hazelcast-client 
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/client-config hazelcast-client-config-3.3.xsd"
  xmlns="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/client-config"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>

  <group>...</group>

  <properties>...</properties>

  <network>
    <port auto-increment="true">5701</port>
    <join>...</join>
  </network>

  <executor-pool-size>10</executor-pool-size>

  <security>
    <credentials>com.hazelcast.security.UsernamePasswordCredentials</credentials>
  </security>

  <load-balancer type="random"/>

</hazelcast-client>
```

After bumping the version of the dependency to 3.6 (or even just 3.5.5), Hazelcast fails to initialize with "Your xsd schema couldn't be load" (sic).

If I add an additional dependency on the `hazelcast-client` artifact (which contains the missing schema file), I get this error instead: "Invalid content was found starting with element 'port'".

Looks like Hazelcast now requires a separate server and client config? What's strange is that I can't find any mention of such a change in the release notes...

Comment: hazelcast-client xsd doesn't support     `<port auto -increment="true">5701</port>` . Also hazelcast always requires separate config file for client and server side since their xsd files are seperate

Comment: You're right, but it's funny that Hazelcast 3.4.3 is perfectly happy with the conf file above that's mixing client and server settings.

Comment: On the other hand, xsi:schemaLocation has changed to https://

Answer (score 3):

The `<port auto-increment="true">5701</port>` is not supported on client side, anyhow strict schema enforcement was added with 3.5.x, the reason why it is loaded on 3.4.x but not on newer versions from 3.5 or 3.6.

Answer (score 0):

Hazelcast has 3 artifacts hazelcast.jar  (the Member/Node/server)  , hazelcast-client.jar (the client)  and hazelcast-all.jar (includes both client and member).  The Members are configured using "hazelcast" config for eg: [hazelcast-config.xml](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/blob/master/hazelcast/src/main/resources/hazelcast-full-example.xml). The clients are configured via "hazelcast-client"  for eg: [refer to Hazelcast code samples](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-code-samples)

Lastly please check the compatibility matrix of hazelcast to determine if there server and client versions are compatible. As per the matrix 3.5.x and 3.6.x are not compatible.  This is available [Here](https://hazelcast.org/imdg/clients-languages/)

Furthermore as explained in the previous answer, Port auto-increment is only valid in case of Members and NOT clients. Port auto-increments is set to increment the port number when more than one Members are started in the same machine.